Dynamically allocated multidimensional arrays in C++
With the recent developments of C++ do we have some common solution for multidimensional arrays which sizes known at run time only and which don’t change during execution?
I found only the Elegantly define multi-dimensional array in modern C++ and it covers static arrays only.
Of course, I can use syntax like:
std::vector<std::vector<T>> array2d;

but for larger number of dimensions it is not very convenient and will hardly work for number of dimensions known at run time. Additionally, it leads to many memory allocations.
I’ve been using my own classes (one for 2D/3D and another for N dimensions) with plain array allocated by operator new and math for addressing elements (like these a[x+y*w]), but maybe there are some changes on the ground to this?
If not, what is the reason that support for 2D/3D dynamically allocated arrays is not a part of std? (With "dynamically allocated" I mean "which sizes known at run time only and which don’t change during execution", as I stated in the beginning of the question).
I guess std::valarray with
std::mdspan and std::slice should be a good step to it, but the syntax of std::mdspan for arrays is way too verbose.
Is there something to nicely put this together for such a task?

Why is std::span too verbose?  It does the job and should be quite efficient. It is not a goal by iteself to write the least amount of characters of code. It is to write code that has some abstraction that the compiler can efficiently use and std::mdspan fits that

Maybe after watching this Multidimensional C++ - Bryce Adelstein Lelbach - CppNorth 2022 you will change your mind :)

but the syntax of std::mdspan for arrays is way too verbose.!!! It seems the interface is via standard square brackets.

"...With the recent developments of C++..." [Requires C++23] Create a class and use std::unique_ptr to allocate a 1D array (of size M * N * ... etc) and overload operator[] for the appropriate number of dimensions
as C++23 supports expr1 [expr2 , expr , ...] see Built-in subscript operator.  Before C++23 write get/set member functions wieh the right number of dimensions as parameters do basic maths to access the 1D array.
